# call-by-name function is evaluated before invoke

Tags: scala

I have a logic look like this:

```scala
def process[T](f1: => T, f2: => T): T = {
  Try { /*Do Something*/ } match {
    case Failure(_) => Try { /*Do something*/ } match {
      case Failure(e) => throw e
      case Success(v1) => 
        // I just need this succeed value be passed to my f1
        // but I dont know how. So...
        implicit val v: V1 = v1
        f1 
    }
    case Success(v2) =>
      // I just need this succeed value be passed to my f1
      // but I dont know how. So...
      implicit val v: V2 = v2
      f2
}
```

then I define `f1` and `f2` and call this `process` function like this:

```scala
// just for describing this problem clearly
// V1, V2 are two successful output types from the above snippet's branches.
// They are two different types.
// Bar just a dummy Object, Unit will do the same
// I use Bar(v) just to show I processed v in this function.
def f1(implicit v: V1): Bar = Bar(v)
def f2(implicit v: V2): Bar = Bar(v)

process(f1, f2)
```

then I got error that says `No implicit found for f1`. Any Help?

Comment: What is `V1`? What is `V2`? What is `Bar`? Please create a [mre].

Comment: `V1`, `V2` are two output types from these branches. `Bar` just a dummy Object, `Unit` will do the same.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65935206/edit) your question to include those details so one that is trying to debug your code can do it easily.

Answer (score 2):

Implicits don't work the way you assumed they do. You would have to pass implicit function type instead of by-name param, but implicit function type is introduced in Dotty:

```
// if it was Dotty
def process[T](f1: (given V1) => Bar, f2: (given V2) => Bar) = ...
```

There are no similar constructs in Scala 2. Closest approximation is handwritten `trait` with `apply` that takes implicit arguments.

```
trait F1 { def apply()(implicit v: V1): Bar }
trait F2 { def apply()(implicit v: V2): Bar }

def process[T](f1: F1, f2: F2): T = {
  Try { /*Do Something*/ } match {
    case Failure(_) => Try { /*Do something*/ } match {
      case Failure(e) => throw e
      case Success(v1) =>
        implicit val v: V1 = v1
        f1()
    }
    case Success(v2) =>
      implicit val v: V2 = v2
      f2()
  }
```

```
def f1: F1 = new F1 { def apply()(implicit v: V1): Bar = Bar(v) }
def f2: F2 = new F2 { def apply()(implicit v: V2): Bar = Bar(v) }

process(f1, f2)
```

Comment: Or juts use a normal function and pass them explicitly.

Comment: Is there any best practice for this kind of logic? I have like four places all use this same logic, just return function difference.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The problem here is I need to pass `succeed output` below to the above function, how should I do this explicitly. help me out

Comment: @JohnJoker what do you mean with _"succeed output"_? If you mean the value inside the `Succeed` in the **pattern matching**, well just passing it... Like this: `f2(v2)` Not sure what you find confusing about that. Of course, you would need to declare `f2` as `V2 => T` instead of `=> T` but again, not sure what is confusing about that, is juts basic function usage.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Not sure what you mean by "just passing it ", If I make a process function like this `def process[T](f1: A => T)`, then I have to call this function like `process(f1(a))`. but this `a` value is produced by logic in the `process` function, how should I know that before running this function.

Comment: No, you just call `process(f)` and inside process you produce `a` and pass it into `f`.

Comment: @JohnJoker oh, sorry, it seems you are pretty new to the language and you do not know that you can pass functions to other functions, that is a basic capability of the language, if you do not understand that you shouldn't be trying to use `implicits` which is probably one of the most advanced and most complex ones. - Anyways, look for _"higher order functions Scala"_.